# Resize reCaptcha on asp.net form

Tags: css, asp.net, recaptcha

I've placed a captcha control on a form which works great etc.

```
            <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" PublicKey=""
            PrivateKey="" Theme="white" />
```

Anyone know how to resize this, mainly width. This might be used on a mobile site and need to be a bit smaller?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS in your code.

```
#recaptcha_image,  
#recaptcha_image img   
{  
width: 100px !important;  
cursor: pointer;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give width of div in which your captcha is reside

or give css to your captcha image width as above explain.

By ID

```
#recaptcha , #recaptcha image
{
width : 180px;
}
```

or you can give width from c#

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-implement-Captcha-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and effectively changed the width of the whole control not only the image

```
 #recaptcha_area
   {
         width: 250px !important;
   }

   #recaptcha_logo
   {
         display: none;
   }
```